# Wrong data pulled from database in cakePHP

Tags: sql, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, sql-server-2014

I am working with cakePHP and am having an issues with microsoft sql server. Basically, I am pulling data about the success rates of different campains. Once of the lines calculates the 'revenue per flyer.'

```
          SUM(o.TotalPrice) / COUNT(cc.CustomerID) AS RevPerFlyer
```

The issue is, cakePHP is calculating this value wrong. Here is my entire query:

```
    SELECT
        c.State,
       '?' AS FlyersMailed,
        COUNT(o.CampaignCustomerID) AS Orders,
      SUM(o.TotalPrice) AS TotalRevenue,
      SUM(o.TotalPrice) / COUNT(cc.CustomerID) AS RevPerFlyer
            FROM Customer c
      INNER JOIN CampaignCustomer cc
            ON c.CustomerID = cc.CustomerID
        LEFT JOIN CustomerOrder o
            ON cc.CampaignCustomerID = o.CampaignCustomerID
      WHERE 1=1
         AND OrderStatusID NOT IN (4,9,10,11,13)
             AND cc.CampaignID = 8
         GROUP BY
             State
         ORDER BY
```

When I run this directly in sql server,I get the correct data.
Example: Here is

> RevPerFlyer for the state AK: 73.924

However, when I run this same exact sql from cake, this is what I get:

> RevPerFlyer for the state AK: 7.2502

Does anyone know what the problem may be? Maybe a problem with sql server?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show some sample data?  And are you certain you're connecting to the same server?

Comment: This is more likely a misunderstanding from what's in the question. You need to show your php code, the query as executed by php and the result of that - in php. Your question needs to be, in principle, reproducible by readers - "I get a different number" does not make that possible.